# How do I let my Facebook friends view my Timeline posts without letting them comment on the posts?

Tags: facebook

I’ve looked through all the options in Facebook’s privacy settings, but I haven’t found how to prevent my friends from leaving comments on my Timeline posts. Whether I share a photo, a link, or a status update, I want them to see it but not comment on it. (I don’t mind if they like or react to my posts, but I can do without that too.)

Is there any way to achieve this? **How can I restrict my friends’ ability to comment on my Timeline posts while still letting them view them?**

---

Additional details to hopefully get this question reopened (see [this meta post](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/a/4956/7584) for context):

**The duplicate target is not helpful since it’s closed and doesn’t allow new answers to be posted.** Facebook updates its site regularly, so a solution may come up for this problem. Currently, the only options are either to restrict the post from being viewed entirely by your friends or to allow them to comment on it. However, neither of these options solves the issue raised in my question. This issue is still presently relevant and I still would like to know if there’s an answer to my question.

I think the problem lies with Facebook’s privacy settings, which they seem to limit on their end. A third-party solution might work, but I’m not sure about that, which is why I posted this question in the first place.

I’ve already looked through all the options in Facebook’s privacy settings, as I already mentioned above. It is possible that I missed something due to Facebook's convoluted and regularly changed settings.

Allowing users to control who can comment on their posts would be useful for the users. Sometimes one just doesn’t want to deal with comments on a Facebook post for various reasons.

Once this question is reopened, I will collaborate and respond to comments and answers about my question.

Answer (score 2):

No, it's not possible. The permissions for a post come all together by the relation this person has to you (group/friend/etc.) - if you can see it, you can comment on it.

The option to disallow comments is available only for groups via the relatively new feature **Turn off comments** (something like that) for individual posts.